# JAX-WS client in Websphere 7 fails with java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/xml

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws

An AXIS2 webservice is deployed in IIS. Using wsdl I generated JAX-WS client. It works fine if I use as standalone i.e, with Oracle JDK.

I have to call the webservice from my application that is deployed in websphere 7. So, i included the jax-ws generated client (as jar) in my application. When the application makes the call to the webservice it fails with java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/xml exception. Websphere 7 uses axis2 related jar files for jax-ws.

Exception details:

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/xml

```
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.msg.StAXMessageProvider.throwXMLStreamException(StAXMessageProvider.java:67)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLStreamReaderImpl.setDocumentEntity(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:401)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLInputFactoryImpl.setDocumentEntity(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:1440)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:1455)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReaderInternal(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:1555)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:1626)
at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils$14.run(StAXUtils.java:618)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.createSecureXMLStreamReader(StAXUtils.java:614)
at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:58)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:191)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:139)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:102)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:66)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:353)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:416)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:581)
... 41 more
```

Caused by: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/xml

```
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(StreamDecoder.java:115)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:93)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.util.encoding.ByteStreamDataSource.convertToCharacterStream(ByteStreamDataSource.java:278)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.util.encoding.PlatformEncodingSupport.loadFromByteStream(PlatformEncodingSupport.java:48)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.util.SimpleParsedEntityFactory.detectEncodingSetSource(SimpleParsedEntityFactory.java:503)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.util.SimpleParsedEntityFactory.setByteStreamSource(SimpleParsedEntityFactory.java:281)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.sax.impl.SAX2ParsedEntityFactory.readFromInputSource(SAX2ParsedEntityFactory.java:122)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.sax.impl.SAX2ParsedEntityFactory.createParsedEntity(SAX2ParsedEntityFactory.java:76)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLStreamReaderImpl.setDocumentEntity(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:394)
... 58 more
```

EDIT: More information.. The webservice is returning the response. It seems websphere is not able to handle the response i.e, fails with exception specified in the question.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have an axis archive file deployed as part of the axis war/jar?

Comment: @Sampada - No, my application deployed in websphere is just having jax-ws client class files (generated) and class to invoke the webservice.

Comment: If i deploy the same application in Jboss, it is working fine. So, the issue is only when it is deployed in Websphere.

Comment: Pls try putting stax2-api.jar in the classpath for websphere

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: @Sampada - I will try this today and let you know the result. sorry, I was on my vacation.

Comment: Once again sorry for late in responding. I tried having stax2-api.jar, but it didnt help. I spent more time on debugging and noticed that the response from the external axis2 webservice (the webservice which i call from my app deployed in websphere) deployed in IIS has content type response header as **text/xml;charset:UTF-8**. This seems to be un-acceptable. I had the team who maintains that external webservice to change such that the response header would be  **text/xml;charset=UTF-8**. Now, websphere is not throwing exception.

Comment: It seems IBM java 6 is not able to parse the response header value (invalid?) **text/xml;charset:UTF-8**. However Oracle Java 6 able to handle it.

Comment: Yep. That's always a problem... When your development environment uses Oracle JDK and deployment uses IBM. Glad you found a solution. Why don't you add it as an answer and accept it? Will help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is because of the invalid response header `*text/xml;charset:UTF-8*. It supposed to be *text/xml;charset=UTF-8*`. IBM JDK is more strict in parsing whereas Oracle JDK is not. Hope this helps if anybody facing exception similar to "java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: text/xml" in Websphere application server while calling any external webservice .